# JQuery: Multiply numbers from to seperate arrays and then get the sum of the results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, multiplication

I have a have a page that allows students to calculate their weighted average. It works by the student adding in their grade in two separate form fields, and they can then add as many rows of form fields as needed. The basic calculations are: Sum of (ECTS * grades) / sum of (ECTS ).

(Note: the page is in danish so some of the language arent in english.)

Right now i do the calculations i PHP and they look like this:

```
if($_POST['karakter'])
{
$karakter=$_POST['karakter'];
}
if($_POST['ects'])
{
$ects=$_POST['ects'];
$samletects = array_sum($ects);
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($karakter); $i++) {
    $result[] = $karakter[$i] * $ects[$i];
}
    $samletv = array_sum($result);
    $fulderesultat = ($samletv/$samletects);
    $afrundet = round($fulderesultat, 2);
if($_POST['karakter'])
{
echo "<h4>Dit vægtede gennemsnit er:</h4><p class='resultatet'>" . $afrundet . "</p>";
} else {
  echo "<h4>Dit vægtede gennemsnit er:</h4><p class='resultatet'>?</p>";
}
```

However i would like to be able to do the calculations i real time, so that you don't loose the grades that you added to the form each time you do the calculations.

This fiddle shows how i add the form fields
http://jsfiddle.net/Chrintz/sv513b5r/26/

The page as it looks now:
http://snittet.dk/

My issue and question is how i do the calculations in Jquery instead of PHP. I have figured out how to get the sum of the ECTS array:

http://jsfiddle.net/Chrintz/omccrobs/

But i can’t figure out how to do this part:
Sum of (ECTS * grades)

to multiply the numbers of one array with the corresponding numbers of the other and then get the sum of the numbers of the new array.

What i basically need help with is to, create two arrays, one containing the grades, one containing the ECTS. Then i want to multiply the corresponding values and thereby creating a third array. I then want to add up the values of the third array and divide it by the added up values of the ects array

Comment: http://needsmorejquery.com/

Comment: what is the grade value??

Comment: Im not shure i know what you mean, but "karakter" is "grade"

Comment: The answer provided by Kooilnc has everything you need and is much better for readability (+1-ed), but just for fun: had the following fiddle going in the background: http://jsfiddle.net/omccrobs/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many (client side) solutions possible here. For example: convert input elements to an `Array` of elements and apply `Array.map/Array.reduce` for calculations.

Something like (auto calculates on value change):

```js
calculate();

// autocalculate
$('body').on('keyup', 'input', calculate);

function calculate(e) {
  var grades    = $('#grades input').toArray();
  var ects      = $('#ects input').toArray();
  
  // calculate values
  var totalEcts = ects.map( function (ectsInput) {return +ectsInput.value || 0;} )
                      .reduce( function (p, n) {return p + n;}, 0 );
  var meanGrade = grades
                   .map( function (gradeInput) {return +gradeInput.value || 0;} )
                   .reduce( function (p, n) {return p+n;}, 0 ) / grades.length;
  var weighted  = grades
                   .map( 
                    function (gradeInput, i) {
                      return (+gradeInput.value || 0) * (+this[i].value || 0);
                    }, ects)
                   .reduce( function (p, n) {return p + n;}, 0 ) / 
                      (totalEcts > 0 ? totalEcts : 1) // avoid division by zero
  
  // display calculated values
  $('#meanGrade').html( 'mean: ' + meanGrade.toFixed(2) );
  $('#totalECTS').html( 'total: ' + totalEcts );
  $('#weightedMean').html( 'sum(grade * ects) / sum(ects): ' + weighted.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
body {font: 12px/15px normal verdana, arial; margin: 2em;}
input {width: 3em; margin-bottom: 0.3em;}
#grades {float:left; margin-right: 3em;}
#meanGrade, #totalECTS, #weightedMean {font-weight: bold; color: green}
#weightedMean {display: inline-block; border-top: 1px dotted #777; margin-top: 0.5em;);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grades">Grades<br>
    <input type="text" class="karakter input" value="5.4"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="karakter input" value="6.2"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="karakter input" value="7.0"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="karakter input" value="6.9"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="karakter input" value="4.3"/><br>
    <span id="meanGrade"> </span>
</div>
<div id="ects">ECTS<br>
    <input type="text" class="ECTS input" value="5"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="ECTS input" value="10"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="ECTS input" value="5"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="ECTS input" value="5"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="ECTS input" value="15"/><br>
    <span id="totalECTS"> </span>
</div>
<p id="weightedMean"></p>
```

By the way: I can't figure out what you mean by *Sum of (ECTS * grades)*. Can you elaborate on that? I work in education and don't know of any judicial system that does a calculation like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i can try to elaborate:

(ECTS * Grade)+(ECTS * Grade)+(ECTS * Grade) = The sum of (ECTS * grades)

Så i multiply the ECTSs with the coresponding grades and then add the individual results together. Hope that makes more sense. 

If we say a student have got the grade 7 and the grade i weighted 5 ECTS and another grade 12 weighted 10 ECTS the calculations would be:


(7 * 5 + 12 * 10) / (5 + 10) = 10.33

Comment: Hi @Christoffer, thanks, that clarifies what you're trying to do.

Comment: Added a map/reduce solution for that to the snippet

Comment: Thank you very much, it is perfect!
Is there a way to make it write out "0" Instead of NaN when the form i empty?

Comment: For empty values you can use (for example):  `+gradeInput.value || 0` and `+ectsInput.value || 0`. If all values are empty (or invalid numbers) the total (from `reduce`) should be 0. You should check that `totalects` is not 0 in that case, to avoid division by zero in the last calculation.

Comment: When i do like that i seemes to have an influence on the calculations

Comment: I modified the snippet somewhat to demonstrate the idea (of `... || 0`)